# call JS file with AJAX

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide some object on my page, so I'm using this code in my JS file:

```
$("span.expandBox").hide();
```

Because I'm using AJAX the JS file doesn't respond all the time

In order to fix it can I call it like this:

```
$(document).("span.expandBox").hide();
```

Comment: How does that *fix it*?

Comment: If you use `.hide()` then you'll get what's called a Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC).  Your user will see the 'object' then it will disappear very quickly (flash) regardless of first view or ajax update.  Always render your html as you want it shown, then manipulate it - in this case give `span.expandBox` elements `style="display:none"` when you generate them.  Then you won't even need the `.hide` thus "fixing" it.

Comment: @user3642988 is it work ? Provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a access to HTML

```
<span class="expandBox" style="display: none">...</span>
```

then inside of ajax callback

```
$("span.expandBox").show();
```

is best way to do this. If not

```
$(document).ready( function () {

     $("span.expandBox").hide();

});
```

would do.

Comment: Hiding in the html then showing as needed is ideal.  However the issue is already described that `$(document).ready` doesn't get called on AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in the ajax complete:

```
function hideSpans(){
    $("span.expandBox").hide();
}
```

so now in your ajax Complete like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:type,
    success:fn,
    error:fn,
    complete:hideSpans // <----here.
});
```

---

Or this can also be done:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("span.expandBox").hide();
});
```

or this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(hideSpans);
```

*NOTE: This will run for every ajax request whose global is not set to false.*